# insert line break using javascript or jquery after nth character

Tags: jquery, split, substring, substr

http://worldalliancemaster/sites/dev/hospitals/hammond/services/cancer/stfranciscancer/Pages/What's-New.aspx

I want to break this url at like the 80th character and have the rest in the next line..
Can someone help me out with jquery ??

```
$(".srch-URL2").each(function() { 
    var html = $(this).html().substring(0,80);
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" "); 
    $(this).html(html); 
});
```

Comment: `substring()` does not return an array. If you [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), you know how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

```
var left = myString.substring(0, 80);
var right = myString.substring(80);
var result = left + '<br />' + right;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uYTPQ/

Answer (score 0):

ThiefMaster is right in that you don't need jQuery to do this:

```
var theURL = "http://worldalliancemaster/sites/dev/hospitals/hammond/services/cancer/stfranciscancer/Pages/What's-New.aspx";
var pieceOne = theURL.substr(0,80);
var pieceTwo = theURL.substr(80, theURL.length);

// Use jQuery for dom manipulation if you want
$('body').html(pieceOne + '<br />' + pieceTwo);
```

Also if you had a really long string and wanted to break it at every 80th character you could do something like this:

```
var theURL = "http://worldalliancemaster/sites/dev/hospitals/hammond/services/cancer/stfranciscancer/Pages/aster/sites/dev/hospitals/hammond/services/cancer/stfranciscancaster/sites/dev/hospitals/hammond/services/cancer/stfranciscancaster/sites/dev/hospitals/hammond/services/cancer/stfranciscancWhat's-New.aspx";

var breakAndInsertURL = function (url) {
    var urlToInsert = '';
    if (url.length <= 80) {
        urlToInsert = url;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < url.length - 80; i += 80) {
            var newPiece = '';
            if (i != 0) {
                newPiece += '<br />';
            }
            newPiece += url.substr(i, i + 80);
            urlToInsert += newPiece;
        }
    }
    $('body').html(urlToInsert);
};

breakAndInsertURL(theURL);
```